# SQL don't increment primary key on INSERT error

Tags: linq-to-sql, sql-server-2008, error-handling, primary-key, auto-increment

Was a bit suprised today to discover that my auto-increment primary key still gets incremented when an insert statement errors, with the result that we have "missing" numbers in our table.

Is there any reason why SQL was designed this way? And is there any way to override this behaviour?

I am accessing through Linq-to-SQL.

Comment: Why is having "missing" numbers such a big deal?  There may be a way to override, but it sounds more like there's a problem with the way you're handling things that needs to be addressed before you hack around identity functionality.

Comment: its a big deal because my boss moans about it :)

Comment: Tell your boss that this is the normal behavior and trying to overwrite it with a manual system is to introduce risk to the data. There is generally no valid reason not to expect to have gaps.

Comment: You wil also get gaps when a record is deleted. And reassigning those numbers can cause a world of data integrity hurt.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

this is by design to deal with concurrency and make it as fast as possible (what would happen if 3 inserts happens at the same time and 1 is rolled back..that would mess up everything)..when an inserts starts sql server determines the value of the identity..if a rollback happens those values are not reused..there is nothing you can really do unless you want to run DBCC CHECKIDENT after every rollback

If you need a query that will identify gaps, take a look at this [How to return all the skipped identity values from a table in SQL Server](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DBProgramming/how-to-return-all-the-skipped-identity-v)

The next version of SQL Server will have `sequences` which might help you with some of this stuff, take a look here: [A first look at sequences in SQL Server Denali](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/a-first-look-at-sequences-in-sql-server)